# Cant push to stack, mips

Tags: printing, stack, mips

I am just trying to print this 'a' to screen, but by first pushing to stack so that I can check whether I did accomplish on pushing to stack or not, seems that I couldn't because it prints a weird character everytime. What's wrong?

```
.data
char: .word 'a'
.text
.globl main
main:
la $t0, char
sub $sp, $sp, 4       #allocate byte for stack
sb $t0, 0($sp)          #push to stack
la $t1, 0($sp)          #I wasnt able to print the top of the stack directly so I tried this


li $v0, 11
la $a0, 0($t1)          #It isnt working anyway.. Prints É
syscall

add $sp, $sp, 4
jr $ra
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am putting my solution after trying the every way that I did to make it work. Still don't have a clue why this one works but, whatever it does.

```
.data
char: .word 'a'
.text
.globl main
main:
la $t0, char
addi $sp, $sp, -4       #allocate byte for stack
sw $t0, 0($sp)          #push to stack
lw $t1, 0($sp)          #load from stack



li $v0, 4
la $a0, 0($t1)          #It now puts 'a'
syscall

add $sp, $sp, 4
jr $ra
```

Comment: you can't subtract an immediate, which is why your code originally didn't work. It did not allocate space on the stack.